# Thinkpad x240: RAM stick not working

Tags: memory, thinkpad

I have two Thinkpad X240.
Laptop 1 has a 4 GB RAM module, functioning properly.
Laptop 2 has a 8 GB RAM module, also functioning properly.

When I put the 8 GB RAM module into laptop 1, I can't get it to start. Instead the laptop makes a beep error message, beeping 3 times, short break, beeping 3 times, short break, beeping 3 times.

The RAM module is apparently not broken.
I assumed that the components are compatible as both are X240, but maybe they are incompatible? How could I check that?

Comment: Is the submodel of one X240 different from the other X240?  Does the 4GB X240 need a BIOS update?

Comment: According to the [Hardware Maintenance Manual](https://thinkpads.com/support/hmm/hmm_pdf/x240s_hm_en_0c11160.pdf) page 37 your beep pattern probably means "Replace the memory module." Have you followed all the advice in the [manual](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/x240_ug_en.pdf) on page 81? Does the 8 GB stick still work inside its original laptop?

Comment: Yes, the 8 GB stick still works inside its original laptop.

Comment: Yes, I followed the advice in the manual on page 81.

Comment: @John how can I find out the submodel of the thinkpads?

Comment: @John how would I know that the 4 GB x240 needs a BIOS update?

Comment: Use Lenovo’s Software update tool and run it. Use Lenovo Diagnostics to get system information. . Otherwise I don’t know if the models are different

Answer (score 1):

You should update the BIOS.

The submodel of one X240 is most likely different from the other X240.

You can find this information with the Lenovo Diagnostic App or Lenovo Vantage (either one).

It may be that the 4GB X240 need a BIOS update if there were changes in BIOS that affected total memory capability.

Different submodels  (I have an X1 20XW   - the 20XW is the submodel).

So two different submodels may easily have 2 different BIOS updates.

I think this address your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the BIOS to the current version did the trick.

Curiously enough, the BIOS version of laptop 2 (which was running perfectly fine with the 8 GB RAM) still has an even older BIOS version. So I don't understand what the problem was and why it was fixed by the BIOS update.